# Google Maps iOS SDK Polygons with holes

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I've been playing with the Google Maps SDK for a few days, seems pretty solid, and easy to use. But I'm having problems trying to draw Polygons with holes inside. Currently if I try to add holes to a path (using a naive, "just add the points there"  way) I get some holes in the polygons, but it looks totally messed up (even if the holes are counterclockwise, and the main polygon is clockwise). Anybody know what to do to get this rendered correctly?

I know that in Android there's a method called `addHole()` that solves this. Is there any similar solution for iOS?

I'm using Google Maps SDK version 1.3.1 (latest available at this time).

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: It took about 2 years, but the "hole" feature is now available for iOS... See the link posted in the accepted answer

Comment: Thanks! I will add an edit to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: Google implemented this feature on Version 1.11.0, **GMSPolygon** now comes with a ***holes*** property.

<strike>Seems that right now there's no way to do this, there is an [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5464&q=apitype=IosSDK&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal) in the google maps api tracker, so let's hope this gets implemented in the near future.</strike>